# Flash game to improve SEO behavioral factor

Tags: flash, seo

Here is the problem I wonder about.
I want my website visitors to stay longer at my site and so I thought about creating a simple flash game somewhere on the sidebar. If visitors engage in this simple game and spend more time on a certain page, will google and others think better about my site?
Thanks

Comment: If you mark my question as unuseful, you could at least give a hint why.

Comment: It's probably considered off topic. In the FAQ you can read about what kind of questions stackowerflow is for: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The metric that Google seems to most care about when measuring user experience is "bounce back rate".  That is how many searchers come back from the site to click on other listing in the Google SERPs, or to refine their query.  I don't think that Google pays much attention to "time on site" at all.   If this flash game is so compelling that people searching get distracted and immediately start playing instead of going back to Google, it will help.